# Show Low Search results with Low Alphabet

Tags: low-search, low-alphabet

I'm wanting to use Low Search to do a simple keyword search on a single channel, but then show the results using Low Alphabet.

I can't quite figure out if this is something you can do 'out of the box' (ie they just integrate because they are super awesome), or if it's something I can 'hack' together in some way.

Has anyone else tackled this?

Cheers.

Comment: So you want to output the search results ordered alphabetically, including using ignore words and/or headings per letter. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep. My current approach is to get a list of entry_ids from the search, then pass it as a parameter - entry_id="1|2|3|4" - to the exp:low_alphabet:entries and exp:low_alphabet:azlist tags (to be fair azlist required a minor hack).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're doing it now -- getting the entry IDs from the search and passing them to the `low_alphabet:entries` tag -- would be the way to do it. There isn't some secret way to seamlessly integrate the two at the moment.

I realise that Low Search could do with a single `:entry_ids` tag to make this easier, but sadly that's not possible at the moment due to the way it combines native and its own filters, and the lack of a proper channel entries API for generating entries.

Comment: Nice one. I was hoping that there was a lovely secret way, but all good. The hack that was required was to add the entry_id parameter to the low_alphabet:azlist tag. Its already on the low_alphabet:entries tag. Search and Alphabet are now playing VERY nicely together. :)

Comment: I'll add the entry_id parameter to the azlist tag to my todo list as a FR.